# How to set value fields of several objects to the same value without Python similar to Alt+Enter?

Tags: objects, vertices, transforms, video-sequence-editor

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> a lot to set the value of a field of several selected objects to the "same value", but I just realized that it doesn't exactly do what I always thought it would do.

I now realize that the value only gets set for the actively selected object and then drags all the values of the other selected objects with it. Currently it might make sense that all the other selected objects field values move along with the active object, but is it possible to set a field of selected objects to exactly the same value with a shortcut similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

[image]

In the case of vertices you would have to do an additional step, which is to scale to zero to align them and then you can move vertices to the same location.

[image]

But there is currently no way to set the volume of several sound strips to the same value if they had previously different values. In this case they would all increment by 0.05 instead of setting them all to 0.05.

[image]

I know I can easily write a python script to solve this but I was interested if Blender has some shortcut key similar to the effect of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> which applies values to all selected object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen tutorials where it is explained that if you select multiple objects and want to have the same values in certain fields you could **either** press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> **or** hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you click in the field to type in the value.

This is simply not correct. In your first example and last example, the cubes and the sound strips, there is a difference between using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+left-click before typing a value or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing a value:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> applies the same difference to all values as the one between the original value you are changing and the new value, so it works relative to the original values.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+left-click and then typing a value is putting the same new value in all fields, it is working absolute on the values.

On the mesh vertices in your second example it's not working the one way or other because above the location values it clearly says *Median:*, which means this is always the median value of all selected vertices. Changing the median will only move them all staying relatively the same to each other, and only scaling them to 0 on one axis aligns them on this axis.

Of course, most times the tutorials get the correct result because often the objects they want to change have the same values, so changing them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will result in having them all the same new values as well. The differing results in both methods only appear if you change objects with different values.

Comment: Aha, yeah before I was wary about pressing ALT first before left clicking then over time I came to believe it was only necessary on Enter. So now I know there is a difference. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie No problem. I added a last paragraph to my answer which explains why tutors often get away with the claim that it would be the same ;)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie See the last but one paragraph.

Comment: oh yes i notice it changes from Transform to Median. so i guess this feature doesn't work for vertices but good there is a workaround with the scaling.